Show that exists such $\delta \gt 0$ that the following equation has exactly one root
The task is to show that exists such $\delta \gt 0$ that $\forall \alpha, \beta \in B_{\delta}(0)$ equation $$e^z - 1 = \alpha z + \beta$$ has exactly one root in circle $B_{\pi}(0)$.
I tried to use Rouche's Theorem like in similar tasks, but I can't pick up functions for the theorem (for example, left side's module can be zero, so I can't separate it from zero and take enough small $\delta$). I will be glad to hear any ideas.

Well, I was wrong when said that module of left side (let it be $f(z)$) can't be separated from zero on the border of $\{|z| \lt \pi\}$.
We can check it directly:
$|f(z)|^2 = e^{2\pi cos(\phi)} - 2cos(\pi sin(\phi)) e^{\pi cos(\phi)} + 1 \ge e^{2\pi cos(\phi)} - 2e^{\pi cos(\phi)} + 1 = (e^{\pi cos(\phi)} - 1)^2$. Functions $f(\phi) = cos(\pi sin(\phi)) - 1$ and $g(\phi) = (e^{\pi cos(\phi)} - 1)^2$ have different zeros and they are continuous, so $|f(z)|^2$ can be separated from zero (inequality is strict or result is more than zero at every point) so my idea works.

Or even eazier: we can found roots of $e^z = 1$ and check that they are not on the border. Connecting it with the fact that function is continuous, we have the solution.
